# Confused with the excel worksheet function - how to remove duplicate and putting non-duplicate ones in a new column

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an Excel sheet which contains data in *`column - A`* and *`Column - B`*. But I am sure that *`Column - B`* contains some data which are also present in *`Column - A`*. In such a case I want to remove data from *`Column - B`*,which are present in *`Column - A`* also.

I tried one approach which gives me the values which are duplicate,putting them in another column.

```
A1: 1   B1:     C1: 3
A2: 2   B2:     C2: 5
A3: 3   B3:     C3: 8
A4: 4   B4:     C4: 2
A5: 5   B5:     C5: 0
```

Used the below worksheet function: in B1 `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$5,0)),"",A1)` and it produced the output as :

```
A1: 1   B1:     C1: 3
A2: 2   B2: 2   C2: 5
A3: 3   B3: 3   C3: 8
A4: 4   B4:     C4: 2
A5: 5   B5: 5   C5: 0
```

Not sure how to get the below output :

```
A1: 1   B1:  8  C1: 3
A2: 2   B2: 10  C2: 5
A3: 3   B3:     C3: 8
A4: 4   B4:     C4: 2
A5: 5   B5:     C5: 0
```

Can anyone help me for the same?

Comment: What's the purpose of column C?

Comment: Column A and Column C is the raw data columns which I have collected from the different sources. Both has more than 5000 values in each of them,while many of them are duplicated. Thus taking column A as a reference, I want to extract non-duplicate values of Column C to put into another column say it is `B`. So that non of the column A or C have loose their data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type this in B1 and autofill down: `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,A:A,1,0)),C1,"")` - this will return in B all values that are NOT in A. If want opposite - swap C1 and "".

Comment: Use then filter for column B to remove unwanted data - either duplicates or empty values.

Comment: @TheMiddleMan could you please provide the actual sample of your data? for the input in your question formula works perfectly for me.